# Jasmine, Karma: fetch-mock not working

Tags: node.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am trying to mock [Fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) in Jasmine/Karma test using [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock)

But it is not working, seems that `fetch-mock` does not mock the request.
I tried to set up the polyfill codes, but the result is the same.

Is there something we have to set up before the testing?

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: Over 6 years later, did you solve this?